In C# AutoMapper, how to map a single object to a list containing that single object, in a ProjectTo compatible way?
I have an odd requirement where I need map a single object to a list containing that single object, in a way that doesn't break IQueryable / ProjectTo mapping.
I am unable to change the projected query or Dtos/Models.
There is a similar question here, but that one is easily answered since it isn't using ProjectTo:
use automapper to map single object into a list of objects
class Team
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
}

class TeamMember
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class TeamMemberProfile : Profile
{
    public TeamMemberProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Dto.TeamMember, TeamMember>(MemberList.None);

        this.CreateMap<Dto.TeamMember, Team>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TeamName, src => src.MapFrom(src => src.TeamName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TeamMembers, src => src.MapFrom(src => new List<TeamMember> { src }));
    }
}

As expected, an AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException occurs:

Unable to create a map expression from . (Dto.TeamMember) to List`1.TeamMember (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TeamMember])

I've tried to implement this using expressions, Expression.ListInit. I've tried to implement this using ConvertUsing(), but I'm not finding the magic mapping config that achieves the required result.
Any idea/pointers? Many thanks.

You can use explicit expansion and not fetch that property with ProjecTo, but generally speaking AM is designed to use the same config for Map and ProjectTo. Ignore and a func or class based resolver or AfterMap would probably work too.

Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve]. We do not see how you execute the mapping via Map() or via ProjectTo(). You have not configured a mapping from Dto.TeamMember to List<TeamMember>.
